# Make a Search view have the same options as a Content view

Tags: 7, views, panels, search

I have created a *Content view* that works perfectly, believing I would later add facets to it once Solr is up and running.

Now that Solr works together with Search API, I realize that to use facets I need my view to be a *Search view*.

Unfortunately now with the view being a *Search view* I can no longer use:
**Contextual filter** - Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)
**Relationship** - Flags: my flag (by any user)
**Field** - Flags: Flag link
**Field** - Computed fields: (values are all 0)
**Field** - Content: Path (Found a work around for this one)

Is there a way to make my *Search view* behave like a *Content view* and therefore have access to all needed functionalities?
Or may be could I use facets on my *Content view*? None of my tests worked though.

Comment: So far what I did is to load the _Content view_ from the _Search view_ using an embeded **View field**. I'm not a fan of this solution for obvious performance issues, but at least it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

H,

This is something I'm still searching for an authoritative solution to/answer on.

This is apparently known issue with Flag and Views, with most people taking programmatic approaches to solve their particular problem.

There's a patch to that should address at least some of your problems here. https://www.drupal.org/node/1362298. This seems to be the closest anyone is to a solution at the moment.